# vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to start a vue.js app from scratch. I'm trying to create an app.vue and an app.js but form some reason I'm getting this error.

> vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

I've been trying to figure out what I've done wrong for 2 hours now and I can't seem to understand what is happening.

#### app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

import Index from './Index.vue'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

Vue.use(VueApollo)

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(Index)
})
```

#### Index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>The following was loaded over Graphql:</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js & Phoenix & GraphQL App',
        user: ""
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

#### Router

```
defmodule StatcastersWeb.Router do
  use StatcastersWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", StatcastersWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
```

#### layout/app.html/eex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Hello Statcasters!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id=”app”></div>
    <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Again I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong and why vue.js can't find the element. Hopefully I've posted enough information for y'all to help me out. Thank you!

Comment: `<div id=”app”>` <- is it really using those quote characters?

Comment: OH MY GOD! great catch phil. I feel dumb. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No need to feel dumb, unless you're using a word processor to write code ;). I imagine you copied it from an example or something like that

Comment: Yep. You are correct. :)